# Ossim setup in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, pci-dss, ossim, alienvault

I have setup OSSIM in my virtual box and its working fine.

I tried to setup OSSIM in AWS cloud, but Alienvault stopped AMI for new customers.

How you are doing this for PCI-DSS as we are SME prefer to go with opensource for log and file integrity monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html documents the steps to import your VM into AWS